# Interleaved Randomized Benchmarking experiment with custom PassManager

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I have a custom `PassManager`, which calibrates a few gates in the circuit in the transpiler pass. I want to conduct an Interleaved Randomized Benchmarking experiment using the class `qiskit_experiments.library.InterleavedRB`.

I'm not able to find any way to add my `PassManager` in the transpiler pass before running the experiments. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Basically, I want to do the following:

1. I have a calibrated rx gate. I want to get the fidelity of this gate. Below is the screenshot of the calibrated gate and its calibrations.

[image]

2. I thought of using the Interleaved Randomized Benchmarking experiment from the qiskit_experiments package for this requirement. Though, after using this I observed on thing that the calibrations from the gate are ignored while conducting the experiment. Below is the screenshot of one of the circuits that is getting executed in the experiments generated by the `InterleavedRB` class. In here, the Interleaved element (Rx) does not have any calibrations which were shown earlier.

[image]

[image]

This raised few questions for me:

a. Is the fidelity of the gate independent of the calibrations? Can I use this fidelity as the gate fidelity of my calibrated gate? I think not, but not sure about this.

b. If it is not independent of the calibrations, how can I get the fidelity of this gate since `InterleavedRB` does not support calibrations in the interleaved element.